# PF6 SelectOneMenu filter is not fired with "Paste" or with "CTRL + Backspace"

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

Using PrimeFaces 6, I am trying to filter my p:selectOneMenu when the user paste a value or when the user delete a value using CTRL + Backspace, in another word, when the value got changed anyhow.

Please find my below code.

```xml
    <p:selectOneMenu id="providerURLDD" widgetVar="providerURLDD"
        value="#{switchProviderBean.selectedProvider}" 
        panelStyle="width:240px" effect="fade" filter="true"
        style="width:240px" filterMatchMode="contains" 
        required="true" 
        requiredMessage="#{msg['selectProvider']}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{switchProviderBean.providerAccounts}"
         var="providerAcc"
         itemLabel="#{providerAcc.code}-#{providerAcc.switchAccountId}-#{providerAcc.name}"
         itemValue="#{providerAcc.switchAccountId}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

I also tried to use Javascript like this:

```js
        function getTextAreaSelection(textarea) {
            var start = textarea.selectionStart,
                end = textarea.selectionEnd;
            return {
                start: start,
                end: end,
                length: end - start,
                text: textarea.value.slice(start, end)
            };
        }
    
    function detectPaste(textarea, callback) {
        textarea.onpaste = function() {
            var sel = getTextAreaSelection(textarea);
            var initialLength = textarea.value.length;
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                var val = textarea.value;
                var pastedTextLength = val.length - (initialLength - sel.length);
                var end = sel.start + pastedTextLength;
                callback({
                    start: sel.start,
                    end: end,
                    length: pastedTextLength,
                    text: val.slice(sel.start, end)
                });
            }, 1);
        };
    }
    
    
    
    var textarea = document.getElementById("switchProviderChoice:providerURLDD_filter");
    detectPaste(textarea, function(pasteInfo) {
        console.log('perform filter');
        PF('providerURLDD').filter();
    });
```

Comment: What version of PrimeFaces?  I feel like this has been fixed in newer PF.

Comment: thanks for your reply @M I am using version 6, and yes it has been fixed in the newer version, my managers refused to update "afraid of other components to be affected as well", is there any way to fix it without updating it (using javascript for example)?.

Comment: Ahh OK so you might have to look through the GitHub Issues commit history and then you can MOnkeyPatch your PF 6 with that fix.  If you find the specific issue that fixed it post it here and I can make you a MonkeyPAtch.,